# Is this OK to call a method that subscribe to IObservable multiple times?

Tags: c#, reactive

I have this method:

```
private void ModerateTravel()
{
    var vm = new ModerateTravelViewModel();
    moderate.ShowModerateTravel(vm);

    Observable.FromEventPattern<string>(h => vm.Error += h, h => vm.Error -= h)
        .Subscribe(DoSomthingOnError);

    Observable.FromEventPattern<string>(h => vm.Close += h, h => vm.Close -= h)
        .Subscribe(DoSomthingOnClose);
}
```

This method is called everytime a button is clicked, showing a child view than wait for error even and or close event.

This method do the job great, what I want to ask is, what is the impact of this code, because this code subscribe to an event but never unsubsrcibe, does this method will cause memory leak?

Is this save to call this method multiple times during the runtime without causing leak or any bad effect?

Comment: Just read a question about spelling mistakes. Yes, they should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Just try it and see if your callback is called once or twice when you call it twice. I mean if someone says “yes, it’s ok”, would you just believe it without verifying? And when you verify it, there’s no need to ask the question anymore.

But *if* you call it twice, what’s absolutely needed is a comment that calling it twice is Ok and why.

Comment: maybe what he mean about "OK" is about the performance, leak, GC, etc, I'm sure he test it before asking here.

Comment: @nyongrand You're an optimist.

Comment: I'm sorry my question is not clear, I update my question, please re read it.